# Magento2 : Display shipped items value in qty box

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, sales-invoice

After submit shipment in admin and complete order, How to display shipped value in quantity box instead of total qty items like below

[image]

I want like this

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyh0f.png]

Comment: If I don't mistaken myself ; Magento seems to generate that array in `src/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/create/items.phtml` so what you probably want to do is to overwrite or extend or whatever the following block : `/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Create\Items $block */` in order to make the modification in the `getItemHtml` and/or `getItemExtraInfoHtml`

Comment: @Claims already my file override am checking in items.phtml can u plz tell me how to achieve the shipped items value instead of ordered items in qty box

Comment: I guess it depends what you really want to achieve. If you want to change the quantity to invoice for each items; then you just need to set the new value in the items and save the item; it will automatically print you the required value. But if it's just something you want to show in the grid, then you need to go deeper to the renderer and once you are in the right column print the value you want.

Comment: @Claims I want to display shipped items value in qty to invoice box as per screenshot . Right now magento displays ordered items value in qty to invoice box but i want to change it to shipped items value

Comment: I mean. Do you want to make that modification effective just there ? Like just in the input box ? If so ==> Renderer using getItemhtml and/or getItemExtraInfoHtml. 
But if you want this to be global (I mean, the data being replaced everywhere, like in pdf invoice / export ); then you just have to change the global value for the item everywhere...in this case observer on order save after and/or may be invoice save after to get the items and modify them with the value you want ? Sorry I don't have any more lead in mind.

Comment: @Claims I want to modify in this input box only. where and which file i need to change. can u plz share me the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131250/discussion-between-user0434-and-claims).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $_item->getQty() use below code for getting shipped value

```
  $_item->getOrderItem()->getQtyShipped()
```